# Orthogonality of Scattering states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, scattering, quantum-states

The scattering states solution  ($E>V_0$) to the time independent Schrodinger equation for a finite square barrier ($V_0$ ) in an otherwise free region has the form:
$$\psi(x)=\begin{cases}e^{i k x} + r(k) e^{-i k x}  &\textrm{for } x<0\\ 
          a(q) e^{i q x} + b(q)  e^{-i q x} &\textrm{for } 0<x<L\\ 
 t(k) e^{i k x}  &\textrm{for } x>L
\end{cases}$$
where $a,b,r$ and $ t$ can be found by applying conditions of smoothness and continuity of $\psi(x)$ over all $x$.
Question: I need to find whether these wavefunctions $\psi$ are mutually orthogonal or not? I need it to find the scattering amplitude between two such states through an interaction potential.

Comment: 1) you only have one wave function ($\psi$) 2) scattering states are not normalizable (so they don't belong to the Hilbert space) and you can't take scalar products or those objects.

Comment: @lcv 1) no, there is a solution for every k. 2) Scattering states are orthonormal in a well defined distributional sense. You’re comment seems irrelevant to the question.

Comment: However, I agree that the question needs quite some improvement. What is q? What are t, r, a and b? We can calculate them in principle, but that is textbook homework stuff.

Answer (score -1):

If they are orthogonal, then their dot product or in this case the probability must be 0. To check whether they are orthogonal or not, just integrate it all over space. If it comes 0 then they are orthogonal.

Comment: Yes I understand that. Can you please suggest me how to handle the Integration of $e^{I k x}$ over a finite region. For example,
$$\int_0^L  dx \quad e^{i k x}$$ and  $$\int_{-\inf}^0 dx \quad e^{i k x}$$