# Why are scattering states orthogonal in general?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, mathematical-physics, scattering, s-matrix-theory

A similar question was asked [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/423820/). Unfortunately, I don't think the question was well-formulated/explained enough for people to actually care about the answer, so let me provide some reason to why I'm thinking about this question.

**BACKGROUND**.
First consider the simple Hamiltonian $H=-\Delta$ on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, so that the "scattering states" are given by $e^{ikx}$. What this actually means is that if $f,g$ were "linear combinations" of the scattering states $e^{ikx}$ such that the corresponding coefficients were normalizable $\int |f(k)|^2 <\infty$, then we have the well-defined relationship
$$
\langle f|g\rangle = \int \bar{f}(k)g(k) 
$$
Also, the scattering states $e^{ikx}$ "diagonalize" H and in fact, we have
$$
\langle f|Hf\rangle=\int k^2 |f(k)|^2
$$
This (rigorously) implies that any function which can be decomposed into the "linear combination" of scattering states $e^{ikx}$ and actually lives in the Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb{R}$ (normalizable) is indeed a "scattering state", i.e., $f$ is an absolutely continuous wave function of $H$ (think of this as a rigorous definition of the scattering subspace). In this case, it just so happens that the all wavefunctions in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ are "scattering states".

However, once we have some complicated Hamiltonian, it's possible that $H$ has both scattering states and bounded states (absolutely continuous and pure point spectrum). However, it would be nice to obtain functions $\phi_k (x)$ which satisfy the same orthogonality relationship as the plane waves $e^{ikx}$, i.e., formally written as
$$
\langle \phi_{k'} |\phi_{k}\rangle = \delta(k'-k)
$$
And also "diagonalize" the Hamiltonian with some spectrum $\epsilon_{k}$. This way, if $f$ is a "linear combination" of scattering states $\phi_k$ such that the coefficients $f(k)$ are normalizable ($L^2$), we would still have the nice relationships
$$
\langle f|g\rangle = \int \bar{f}(k)g(k), \quad \langle f|Hf\rangle = \int \epsilon(k)|f(k)|^2
$$

**PROBLEM**. Now, I know that there are indeed rigorous proofs of the existence of scattering states $\phi_k$ (cf. Barry Simon Vol 3). However, they are quite complicated and tedious to actually go through, so I though it would be much more insightful to just work through a one-dimensional example. Indeed, usually the ansatz (left incoming) scattering states is given by
\begin{align}
\phi_k (x) &= e^{ikx} +r_ke^{-ikx}, \quad x<0 \\
&= t_k e^{ikx}, \quad x>0
\end{align}
where $|r_k|^2+|t_k|^2 =1$ and $\bar{r}_k t_k +\bar{t}_k r_k =0$. (You also have right-incoming states but let me ignore those for now). Now of course, since there's some potential $V$ near $x=0$, the scattering states $\phi_k$ is somewhat different near $x$, but let's consider the limiting case where the region of nonzero $V$ is quite small just for simplicity. Then you would think that **just** from the unitary property of the $S$-matrix (i.e., the relationship between $r_k,t_k$), we should be able to prove that
$$
\langle \phi_{k'} |\phi_k\rangle = \delta(k'-k)
$$
However, writing this out actually involves knowing the relationship of $r,t$ for different $k',k$. For example, we would need to know that $\bar{r}_{k'} r_k + \bar{t}_{k'} t_k=1$ for this orthogonality to hold, but in general, we do not have this. Indeed, the main problem is that since we are integrating from $-\infty \to 0$ or $0\to \infty$ instead of $-\infty \to\infty$, we have an extra term, e.g.,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{-i(k'-k)x} = \frac{i}{k'-k+i0^+} = i \text{p.v.}\left( \frac{1}{k'-k} \right) +\pi \delta(k'-k)
$$
While
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-i(k'-k)x} = 2\pi \delta(k'-k)
$$

**EDIT.** @Andrew has provided a simple example [here](https://www.reed.edu/physics/courses/Physics342/html/page2/files/Lecture.11.pdf), or more specifically, Problem 11.3, in which all the problems *magically* cancel each other out and we obtain the nice looking formula
$$
\langle \phi_{k'}|\phi_k \rangle = \delta(k'-k).
$$
Very odd indeed!

**EDIT**. The rigorous proof can be found in Barry Simon Vol 3
, section Quantum Scattering III: Eigenfunction expansion

Comment: I don't think so. For example, in the appendix of [Phys. Rev. B 69, 184511](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.69.184511), the authors gives the formula for $t,r$, and for different $k',k$, we do not actually have that condition. There's also an extra term in $\langle \phi_{k'} |\phi_k\rangle$ of $(\bar{r}_{k'} + r_k) \text{p.v.}(k'+k)^{-1}$ which doesn't seem to vanish (though entirely imaginary)

Comment: The form of your energy eigenstates is only correct for a delta function potential. Maybe you need to use the explicit form of $r$ and $t$ for a delta function potential to get this to work? Problem 11.3 of https://www.reed.edu/physics/courses/Physics342/html/page2/files/Lecture.11.pdf asserts your claim should be true, although the problem is to check that the bound state is orthogonal to the scattering states (not quite what you want but maybe a good starting point?)

Comment: I'm also not sure that $1=\bar{r}_{k'} r_k + \bar{t}_{k'} t_k$ needs to be true for orthogonality. There should also be terms linear in $r_k$ (cross terms expanding the $x<0$ expression). Given that I'm pretty sure this will only work if you use the explicit formulas for $r$ and $t$, I don't think you can ignore these terms.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Everything cancels out if we also consider the terms linear in $r_k$.

Comment: Woohoo! That's satisfying! If you wrote this up I'd upvote your answer :)

Comment: So **Reed** & Simon. Which equation?

Comment: Tip: [Let's not have posts look like revision histories](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5886/2451).

Comment: Should I expect the orthogonality properties of scattering states to change if the equation of motion has a term linear in spacial derivative? (say just in 1+1 dimensions for simplicity). In particular, are left-incoming and right-incoming still orthogonal with respect to each other?

Comment: @Rudyard I think that's probably true as long as your Hamiltonian is self-adjoint and some other general assumptions. Indeed, there are rigorous proofs (none of which I have gone through btw). This question was more so that I could work out a simple example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I thought I should provide a sketch of the proof. I will be a little sloppy with regularization, but if you go through everything rigorously, the basic idea is the same. Indeed, from the link, we have
$$
r_k = \frac{i}{k-i}, \quad t_k = \frac{k}{k-i} 
$$
Where I have set the unimportant constants to $=1$. Then we have
\begin{align}
\langle \phi_{k'} |\phi_k\rangle &=\int_{-\infty}^0 \left(e^{-i(k'-k)x} + \bar{r}_{k'} r_k e^{+i(k'-k)x} +\bar{r}_{k'} e^{i(k'+k)x} +r_k e^{-i(k'+k)x}\right) +\int_0^\infty \bar{t}_{k'} t_k e^{-i(k'-k)x} \\
&=\frac{i}{k'-k +i0^+} +(\bar{r}_{k'}r_k+\bar{t}_{k'}t_k) \frac{i}{k-k'+i0^+} +r_k \frac{i}{k'+k+i0^+}-\bar{r}_{k'} \frac{i}{k'+k-i0^+}
\end{align}
Notice that
$$
\bar{r}_{k'}r_k+\bar{t}_{k'}t_k = 1 - \frac{i(k-k')}{(k'+i)(k-i)}
$$
And that
$$
r_k \frac{i}{k'+k+i0^+}-\bar{r}_{k'} \frac{i}{k'+k-i0^+} = -\frac{1}{(k'+i)(k-i)}
$$
Hence, we have
$$
\langle \phi_{k'} |\phi_k\rangle = (2\pi) \delta(k'-k)
$$